# Sphalerite type structure

Tags: solid-state-chemistry

There are binary diamond type structures for example S and Zn form sphalerite. I thought the reason this formed was because of the big difference in the radii of the atoms that allows the smaller atom to fit into the tetrahedral hole that the bigger atoms form. However GaAs also forms sphalerite type structure, their radii are not that different. Why do Sphalerite type structures form?